How do I install graphstream into Eclipse IDE so I can use its library?
I am quite new to programming and am looking to create a graph algorithm program. I have been using Eclipse IDE Java and want to install graphstream to assist me however have encountered multiple issues when following the installation tutorial such as the editor not having a main type or the Pom.xl file not having the correct dependencies. Would anyone be able to assist with a much more basic step by step guide or video for installing graph stream into Eclipse IDE? Any help is much appreciated!
Some errors included when running the graphstream program an error occurred where it couldn’t find the main class.

Note that your question is off-topic for SO. Refer to What topics can I ask about here, specifically this part: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Having said that, you can ask for help with your current problem by giving details of the problems you are encountering and posting your pom.xml file.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
